Renaming "idapro-plugins" and "idapro-sdk"
Was partially raised by 0xc0000022l here, there are a couple of questions regarding the idapro-plugins and idapro-sdk:

Whether "idapro" should be replaced with the simplistic "ida" in both tags.
Whether idapro-plugins whould be made singular (idapro-plugin).


I strongly believe tags should be renamed to ida-sdk and ida-plugins.
The rename from "idapro" to "ida" is aligned with a similar older change discussed here and with the current status of idapro being a synonym of ida.
If this answer gets upvoted I'll rename the tags and create the needed synonyms.

The rename from the plural idapro-plugins to the singular idapro-plugin seems more natural to me, but I cannot provide any actual arguments.
If this answer gets upvoted I'll rename idapro-plugins to idapro-plugin(or ida-plugin).
